# Collect doesn't work correctly

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have this expression

[image]

```
-((\[Lambda] \[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) (-1 + Subscript[e, 
     1]))/(2 (\[Lambda] + 2 \[Mu]) Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\))) + (\[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[e, 2])/(
 2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\))
```

Which can be easily transformed to this

[image]

```
(\[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\))/(2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\)) (Subscript[e, 
   2] - \[Lambda]/(\[Lambda] + 2 \[Mu]) (Subscript[e, 1] - 1))
```

But

[image]

```
Collect[-((\[Lambda] \[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) (-1 + Subscript[e, 
     1]))/(2 (\[Lambda] + 2 \[Mu]) Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\))) + (\[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[e, 2])/(
 2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\)), (\[Chi]^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(0\), \(2\)]\))/(2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(r\), \(2\)]\))]
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Just do `Simplify[expr]` and it gives you pretty much what you want  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Ua9.png) It is not always to get the exact form of the expression one wants, but the above does factor the term $\frac{B_0^2 \chi ^2}{2 \mu _0 \mu _r^2}$ as you see from the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Using an intermediate variable `texpr` to store the common factor:

```
Clear["Global`*"]         
expr=-((λ χ^2 
Subsuperscript[B, 0, 2] (-1 + Subscript[e, 
     1]))/(2 (λ + 2 μ) Subscript[μ, 0] 
Subsuperscript[μ, r, 2])) + (χ^2 
Subsuperscript[B, 0, 2] Subscript[e, 2])/(
 2 Subscript[μ, 0] 
Subsuperscript[μ, r, 2]);

rule = Intersection @@ expr -> texpr

res = (expr /. rule // Simplify // Times[Most@#, Apart@Last@#] &) /. 
  texpr -> Intersection @@ expr
```

$$\frac{B_0^2 \chi ^2 \left(e_2-\frac{\left(e_1-1\right) \lambda }{\lambda +2 \mu }\right)}{2 \mu _0 \mu _r^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

To improve readability and simplify Copy&Paste,  I copy Mathematica cells by a right click on the cell bracket and chose "copy as text".

Then I paste it into  a
{your code here} cell from the toolbar.

```
expr=-((\[Lambda] \[Chi]^2 Subsuperscript[B, 0, 2] (-1 + Subscript[e, 1]))/
(2 (\[Lambda] + 2 \[Mu]) Subscript[\[Mu], 0] Subsuperscript[\[Mu], r, 2])) + (\[Chi]^2 Subsuperscript[B, 0, 2] Subscript[e, 2])/
( 2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] Subsuperscript[\[Mu], r, 2])
```

Rearranging the code block I manage by Shift+Enter line feed, that preserves the code block. If it is  broken, I select it with the mouse and click on |{}| in the toolbar again.

So much about making life easier for transfer from and to the Mathematica window, as far as I learned it the last week.

By trial and error I found the followling weights for ComplexityFunction in Simplify, that is doing the job.

```
    FullSimplify[expr // Factor // FullSimplify, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (-100 LeafCount[#] + 10000 Count[#, _Times, \[Infinity]] &)]

(\[Chi]^2 Subsuperscript[B, 0, 2]
 (-((\[Lambda] (-1+Subscript[e, 1]))/
(\[Lambda]+2 \[Mu]))+Subscript[e, 2]))/
(2 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] Subsuperscript[\[Mu], r, 2]).
FromCharacterCode[ 16^^1F192]
```

Finally for control of the graphics representation I use

```
makeimg[expr_]:=Graphics[{Style[Text[expr .  FromCharacterCode[ 16^^1F192]],10]},ImageSize->150]
```

and copy the graphics

[image: Output as Graphics[Text[..]]]